# Components of a 2D vector field satisfy Cauchy Riemann conditions implies the finite transformation is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-fields, cauchy-riemann-equations, conformal-field-theory

I am reading M. Schottenloher's book on Conformal field theory.

[https://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~schotten/LNP-cft-pdf/01_978-3-540-68625-5_Ch01_23-08-08.pdf](https://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/%7Eschotten/LNP-cft-pdf/01_978-3-540-68625-5_Ch01_23-08-08.pdf)

On page 19 after Proposition 1.12, he considers a vector field $X=(u,v)$, where $u_x=v_y$, $u_y=-v_x$. And then he claims that the one-parameter groups for $X$ are also holomorphic. I wonder how to show this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to prove it.  Let $(\varphi_t)$ be the one-parameter group generated by $X$.  For fixed $t$, let $\psi_n$ be the approximation to $\varphi_t$ given by the $n$-step Euler method.  Since $X$ is holomorphic, $\psi_n$ is holomorphic for each $n$.  As $n\to\infty$, $\psi_n$ converges to $\varphi_t$ locally uniformly.  Thus, $\varphi_t$ is also holomorphic.